# Log-likelihood function for GARCHs parameters

Tags: time-series, likelihood, garch

I am writing a bachelor thesis on the evaluation of value-at-risk using GARCH models. To estimate the parameters for the GARCH models, I explained that we can do it with maximum likelihood as shown in the picture and that theta can be the parameters we want to estimate, but my teacher wants to know what is the maximum likelihood function for the parameters of the models (GARCH, EGARCH, APARCH) and not only for the distributions. Can anyone help me understand this or give me some pointers?     [image]